# Anagrams in Python using lists

Tags: python, string, list, anagram

Imagine we have following list of strings:

```
Input: ["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]
```

The output of our program should group each set of anagram and return them all together as a list as following:

```
Output:
[
  ["ate","eat","tea"],
  ["nat","tan"],
  ["bat"]
]
```

My current solution finds the first set of anagrams but fails to detect the other two and instead, duplicates the first groups into the list:

```
class Solution(object):
    def groupAnagrams(self, strs):
        allResults=[]
        results=[]
        temp=''
        for s in strs:  
          temp=s[1:]+s[:1]
          for i in range(0,len(strs)):
              if temp==strs[i]:
                results.append(strs[i])
          allResults.append(results)      
        return allResults
```

and the output is:

```
[["ate","eat","tea"],["ate","eat","tea"],["ate","eat","tea"],["ate","eat","tea"],["ate","eat","tea"],["ate","eat","tea"]]
```

How to fix this issue?

**EDIT:**
I have fixed the duplication in appending by appending the `results` into `allResults` outside of second loop:

```
class Solution(object):
def groupAnagrams(self, strs):
    allResults=[]
    results=[]
    temp=''
    for s in strs:  
      temp=s[1:]+s[:1]
      for i in range(0,len(strs)):
          if temp==strs[i]:
            results.append(strs[i])
    allResults.append(results) 
    print(results)
    return allResults
```

Yet, it does not detect the other two sets of anagrams.

Comment: Hints: What is the value of `results` when you enter the second iteration of the loop? What is the value of `allResults` on each iteration? (Print them and look.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Do you mean right before `if temp...`?

Comment: Print them after appending to `allResults`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Understood, I know the trouble is appending at wrong loop, but as Python has no  `{}` for blocks and uses indentation instead, it is confusing me. Am I getting it correctly?

Comment: @molbdnilo The duplication in appending has been fixed, yet, it does not detect the other two sets of anagrams. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

you can do it using defaultdict of python in-built collections library and sorted :

```
In [1]: l = ["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]

In [2]: from collections import defaultdict

In [3]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [4]: for x in l:
   ...:     d[str(sorted(x))].append(x)

In [5]: d.values()
Out[5]: dict_values([['eat', 'tea', 'ate'], ['tan', 'nat'], ['bat']])
```

to fix your the solution you need add the variable to check is allready added, for exanmple(and the while walk through the `strs` i use enumerate for little performance in the search of the anagrams):

```
class Solution(object):
    def groupAnagrams(self, strs):
        allResults = []
        added = set([])
        temp=''
        for i, s in enumerate(strs):
            results = []
            unique_s = "".join(sorted(s))
            if unique_s in added:
                continue
            else:
                added.add(unique_s)
            for x in strs[i:]:
              if unique_s=="".join(sorted(x)):
                results.append(strs[i])
            allResults.append(results)

        print(added)

        return allResults
```

Comment: very nice, but can you modify my own code? I would like to know where in my code is wrong in order to improve my understanding from python as a new comer.

Comment: Using `set` to find the anagrams won't work if you have duplicate letters in some words. Your code would consider 'hat' and 'that' to be anagrams.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque the main trouble was using set i fixed, thank you

Comment: @Ionesome i extended the answer for your solution

Comment: It seems it has a bit of [problem](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/168665425/). In my opinion, your code changes input strs and returns them as output. I guess they shouldnt get changed.

Comment: not the input data not changed you can test it yourself

Comment: I have sent you the link that shows the output is not identical with the expected solution. I dont know why.

Comment: i don't regist on the system you use for link can yoy try to use https://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> lst =  ["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]
>>> 
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> f = lambda w: sorted(w)
>>> [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=f), f)]
[['bat'], ['eat', 'tea', 'ate'], ['tan', 'nat']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you implemented your function, you are only looking at rotations of the strings (that is you shift a letter from the beginning to the end, e.g. a-t-e -> t-e-a -> e-a-t). What your algorithm cannot detect is single permutations were you only switch two letters (n-a-t -> t-a-n). In mathematical language you only consider the even permutations of the three letter strings and not the odd permutations.

A modification of your code could for example be:

```
def get_list_of_permutations(input_string):
  list_out = []
  if len(input_string) > 1:
    first_char = input_string[0]
    remaining_string = input_string[1:]
    remaining_string_permutations = get_list_of_permutations(remaining_string)
    for i in range(len(remaining_string)+1):
      for permutation in remaining_string_permutations:
        list_out.append(permutation[0:i]+first_char+permutation[i:])
  else:
    return [input_string]
  return list_out

def groupAnagrams(strs):
  allResults=[]
  for s in strs:  
    results = []
    list_of_permutations = get_list_of_permutations(s)
    for i in range(0,len(strs)):
      if strs[i] in list_of_permutations:
        results.append(strs[i])
    if results not in allResults:
      allResults.append(results)     
  return allResults
```

The output is

```
Out[218]: [['eat', 'tea', 'ate'], ['tan', 'nat'], ['bat']]
```

**Edit:** modified the code to work with all lengths of strings.

Comment: How to fix it then?

Comment: The problem with your code is that is only effective to terms with length of 3.

Comment: Can you please format your code? indentations are not proper and it is not easy to run your code.

Comment: Should be fixed now. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using only lists, as requested in the title of the question:

The second line `s_words` takes all the letters of each `word` in `words`, sorts them, and recreates a string composed of the sorted letters of the word; it creates a list of all the these sorted letters strings, in the same order as the original sequence of words --> this will be used to compare the possible anagrams (the letters of anagrams produce the same string when sorted)

The 3rd line `indices` hold `True` or `False` values, to indicate if the corresponding word has been extracted already, and avoid duplicates.

The following code is a double loop that for each s_word, determines which other s_word is identical, and uses its index to retrieve the corresponding word in the original list of words; it also updates the truth value of the indices.

```
words = ["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]
s_words = [''.join(sorted(list(word))) for word in words]
indices = [False for _ in range(len(words))]
anagrams = []
for idx, s_word in enumerate(s_words):
    if indices[idx]:
        continue
    ana = [words[idx]]
    for jdx, word in enumerate(words):
        if idx != jdx and not indices[jdx] and s_word == s_words[jdx]:
            ana.append(words[jdx])
            indices[jdx] = True
    anagrams.append(ana)

print(anagrams)
```

#### output:

```
[['eat', 'tea', 'ate'], ['tan', 'nat'], ['bat']]
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code? Specially the second line.

Comment: I added some explanations that, together with reading the code will help you understand how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

```
from itertools import permutations

word_list = ["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]
anagram_group_list = []

for word in word_list:

    if word == None:
        pass
    else:
        anagram_group_list.append([])

        for anagram in permutations(word):
            anagram = ''.join(anagram)

            try:
                idx = word_list.index(anagram)
                word_list[idx] = None 

                anagram_group_list[-1].append(anagram)

            except ValueError:
                pass # this anagram is not present in word_list

print(anagram_group_list)
# [['eat', 'ate', 'tea'], ['tan', 'nat'], ['bat']]
```

after refactoring code and stopping it from producing redundant result  your code still doesn't give expected result as logic for producing anagram is not completely correct

```
def groupAnagrams(word_list):
    allResults=[]
    results=[]

    for idx,s in enumerate(word_list):
        if s == None:
            pass
        else:
            results = [s] # word s is added to anagram list

            # you were generating only 1 anagram like for tan --> ant but in word_list only nat was present
            for i in range(1,len(s),1):
                temp = s[i:]+s[:i] #anagram 
                    # for s = 'tan' it generates only 'ant and 'nta'
                    # when it should generate all six tna ant nta _nat_ atn tan

                if temp in word_list:
                  results.append(temp)
                  word_list[word_list.index(temp)] = None

            allResults.append(results) 

    return allResults

print(groupAnagrams(["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]))
# [['eat', 'ate', 'tea'], ['tan'], ['nat'], ['bat']]
```

Answer (score -1):

The detection of anagrams of words consisting *of unique characters* can be done by comparison between `set`s. *[See comment for a general solution]*

```
words = ["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]

anagrams = []

for w in words:
    m = [w2 for w2 in words if set(w2) == set(w)]
    if m not in anagrams:
        anagrams += [m]

print(anagrams)
```

Output

```
[['eat', 'tea', 'ate'], ['tan', 'nat'], ['bat']]
```

---

**EDIT**

For words with duplicate characters a *multi-set* approach can be used. A multi-set can be modeled with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

words = ["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat", "cia", "aci"]

# group per index
d = {}
multi_sets = list(map(Counter, words))
for i, w in enumerate(words):
    i_reference = multi_sets.index(Counter(w)) # always 1st match
    d.setdefault(i_reference, []).append(words[i])

anagrams = list(d.values())

# inplace sort: group per size of family of anagrams
anagrams.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
print(anagrams)
```

**Remark:** ordering a multi-set is highly non-trivial and the usual methods  `__lt__`, `__gt__`, ... are not implemented. As a consequence `sorted` **cannot** be used. Comparison is still possible with `__eq__` or `__ne__` which are both *naturally* supported by `Counter`.

Comment: "An Anagram is a word or phrase formed by rearranging the letters of a different word or phrase, typically using all the original letters EXACTLY ONCE."
Your solution is not working, because it's not considering the occurrences.
eg: ["eat","eatt"] results as anagram but it's not.

Comment: @arst3k Thanks for the comment. The error is due to the implementation with `set` which remove all duplicates characters. I will figure out an different implementation

Comment: Instead of completely changing your approach to the problem, you could have just changed 'set(w2) == set(w)' with 'sorted(w2) == sorted(w)'

Comment: @arst3k mmm yes, it makes sense... just didn't see it:) I didn't remember why I come out with that answer so I preferred to restart a look at the problem from another prospective. Nice trick your comment!

Comment: The _multi-set_ solution is much more performant than the original with (accordingly to the update in the comment)